# Can I Alter SQL Azure ServiceObjective (Pricing Tier) Using SQL

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

So I use Visual Studio Database project to publish my database to Azure.

By Default this publishes the database as `S0` pricing tier. I then have to log into the Portal and change the Pricing tier to `S1`.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41472262/2987066) I can see someone set the `ServiceObjective` property when creating a database like so:

```
CREATE DATABASE 
[{databaseName}] 
(MAXSIZE={maxSize}, EDITION='{edition}',SERVICE_OBJECTIVE='{serviceObjective}'
```

After Changing the Pricing tier in the portal I run this command:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('MyDatabaseName', 'ServiceObjective')
```

and it returns `S1` so I am sure `ServiceObjective` is the right property

But my question is can I set this property after Creating a Database using `Alter`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Can I Alter SQL Azure ServiceObjective (Pricing Tier) Using SQL

It seems this is possible(i didn't tested yet),docs state this as well:
[Changing the edition, size and service objective for an existing database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-azure-sql-database)

```
ALTER DATABASE [db1] 
MODIFY
 (EDITION = 'Premium', MAXSIZE = 1024 GB, SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'P15');
```

Below is the total syntax for SQLAZURE alter

```
-- Azure SQL Database Syntax  
ALTER DATABASE { database_name }  
{  
    MODIFY NAME =new_database_name  
  | MODIFY ( <edition_options> [, ... n] )   
  | SET { <option_spec> [ ,... n ] }   
  | ADD SECONDARY ON SERVER <partner_server_name>  
      [WITH (\<add-secondary-option>::= [, ... n] ) ]  
  | REMOVE SECONDARY ON SERVER <partner_server_name>  
  | FAILOVER  
  | FORCE_FAILOVER_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS  
}  

<edition_options> ::=   
{  

      MAXSIZE = { 100 MB | 250 MB | 500 MB | 1 … 1024 … 4096 GB }    
    | EDITION = { 'basic' | 'standard' | 'premium' | 'premiumrs' }   
    | SERVICE_OBJECTIVE =   
                 {  'S0' | 'S1' | 'S2' | 'S3'| 'S4'| 'S6'| 'S7'| 'S9'| 'S12' |
                 | 'P1' | 'P2' | 'P4'| 'P6' | 'P11'  | 'P15' | 
                 | 'PRS1' | 'PRS2' | 'PRS4' | 'PRS6' |
                 | { ELASTIC_POOL (name = <elastic_pool_name>) }   
                 }   
}  

<add-secondary-option> ::=  
   {  
      ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = { ALL | NO }  
     | SERVICE_OBJECTIVE =   
                 {  'S0' | 'S1' | 'S2' | 'S3' | 'S4'| 'S6'| 'S7'| 'S9'| 'S12' |
                 | 'P1' | 'P2' | 'P4'| 'P6' | 'P11' | 'P15' |
                 | 'PRS1' | 'PRS2' | 'PRS4' | 'PRS6' |  
                 | { ELASTIC_POOL ( name = <elastic_pool_name>) }   
                 }   
   }  

 [;]
```

Comment: I've tested this successfully as well. Interestingly, the documentation is missing from the linked page as of 2018-08-27.

Answer (score 4):

You can run an ALTER DATABASE statement and need to specify as a minimum the Edition and the Service Objective as shown below:

```
ALTER DATABASE [DBName] MODIFY(EDITION='Standard', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE='S2')
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, you can wrap the SQL commands in an Azure Logic App and give it a schedule.
And since you can change the tier with SQL, **you can easily set it up to scale up and down periodically**, e.g. switch to 100 DTUs every morning, and switch back to 10 DTUs every evening.